# Font Awesome 5 icons not showing up

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I use codeigniter and Font Awesome 5 I have download the latest version of font awesome 5 how ever for some reason my icon is not showing up

> Question How to get the icon to show up in font awesome 5 I am using xampp

It should show next to the sign in text there are no errors in dev console

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/bs/css/bootstrap.css');?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/stylesheet.css');?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/fa/web-fonts-with-css/fontawesome-all.min.css');?>">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js');?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/popper.min.js');?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/bs/js/bootstrap.js');?>"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('login');?>" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Sign in</a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13):

The instructions on the font awesome site for getting 5.0.10 running are a little confusing when it comes to what files should go where. I ran into this exact problem and solved it with these steps:

> 1. Create the following directory
>
>    **/static/styles/fontawesome/css**
> 2. Copy and paste all fontawesome css files into the above directory
> 3. Copy the entire webfonts directory and paste in into **/static/styles/fontawesome** (so that it is at same level as the css
>      directory)
> 4. Add the following to your html header
>      `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.css">`
> 5. Add icon tags to your code using the corresponding version documentation (5.0.10)
>      `<i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>`

Note: Be sure to use only icons from the free set if you do not have a pro licence.
https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free

This might not work for everyone but hope it helps someone out with this frustrating problem!

Comment: how we can use font awesome 5 with looping ?

Comment: on fontawesome 4,, we can use '<i class="fa '.$icon.' "></i>'
how about on fontawesome 5? how to add fa, fas, fab, far, fal?

Comment: Working as charm for me. Thanks mate :)

Comment: 1+ for the `use only icons from the free set`

Answer (score 3):

you are using `fas fa-sign-in-alt` which is pro version of Font Awesome 5 you need to get the licence then only you would be able to use them. you can get your icon from [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons)

Reference https://fontawesome.com/pro

Comment: Not true, at least in version 5.3.1 is it free (solid version)

Comment: @Michal may be now I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this thread is old. However, posting this in case it helps someone.

I too ran into the same issue in Font Awesome 5 with `fas fa-virus`. As @zipzit mentioned, while using a CDN, the integrity hash does matter. The best option, in this case, is to signup with Font Awesome, create a kit and add that to the `<head>` tag of the `html` file. This way, all the free icons ("fa","fab","fas","far","fal") seem to work.

**Example**:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxx.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case, i get square icon on fontawesome on localhost because i am not set my base_url value in config\config.php

```
$config['base_url']    = ''
```

it's getting work when i change my base_url to

```
$http = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '') . '://';
$newurl = str_replace("index.php","", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$http" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "" . $newurl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter 3/Bootstrap 4/Font Awesome 5

**PHP FILE**

1. header.php file with CSS Implementing Plugins. Change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">` to the following:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css');?>">`

**CODEIGNITER 3**

2. application/config/config.php. Change `$config['base_url'] = '';` to the following:

`$http = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '') . '://';
$newurl = str_replace("index.php","", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$http" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "" . $newurl;`

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using Font Awesome via CDN and Javascript download (both solid.js and fontawesome.js) the integrity hash matters.  In my case I got lazy, and updated the script link to a newer version, without updating the hash. I could see the two downloaded files in Chrome devtools, but they were non functional.. The integrity hash has to absolutely match to its original source...

```
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Oops.

Answer (score 0):

for me i did the following steps:

1. import these files in your .scss file (change the path related to your project scss folder):

```css
@import "../_fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/scss/fontawesome";
@import "../_fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/scss/regular";
@import "../_fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/scss/brands";
@import "../_fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/scss/solid";
@import "../_fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/scss/v4-shims"
```

2. change "/fontawesome/scss/_variables.scss" file(change path related to compiled css file and webfonts folder):

> $fa-font-path: "../fontawesome/webfonts" !default;